# Django CMS site permissions to plugins

Tags: django, django-cms, django-sites

I have site and several subdomains. Like www.example.com, www.is.example.com, www.cs.example.com. Also users which can administrate this sites. Each user can administrate several sites. I want that each site have own permissions to plugins.

How I can implement this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign edit permissions on pages on different domains to different users to achieve this, if I understand correctly your use case

Comment: thanks for answer, but this solution works only when one user moderate one domain or subdomain,  in my case one user can moderate several sites

Comment: you can add permissions on pages of different sites, also

Comment: I want to that each site have own permissions to some plugins, so when admin enter to site he can not put this plugin, because this don't have permissions do this

Comment: plugins does not have specific permissions, only pages. For plugins you can use django permission but they are not restricted on sites (I don't know if applications that handle per-site permissions exists)